# How can I make ctrl+right/left arrow stop changing Desktops in Lion?

Tags: macos, mission-control

<kbd>⌃ Control</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> switches desktops.

I actually had this enabled in Spaces on Snow Leopard, but I'd like to turn this off because I use those key combinations when editing in Eclipse. How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control and change the settings for "Move left a space" and "Move right a space" or disable them completely.

Comment: It's easy to mix up and go to "System Preferences > Mission Control > Shortcuts" instead, where you will only see options for the Ctrl + Up/Down shortcuts, but not the Ctrl + Left/Right ones!

Comment: In OS X Catalina these options are in the "System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control"

Comment: @rleelr : Your comment saved me. Thanks :)

Comment: Interestingly, after doing this, CTRL-LEFT ARROW works but RIGHT doesn't...?

Comment: Absolutely needed when using virtual desktop on Mac, but also connected through RDP to a Windows Machine. You do want Ctrl+Arrows to work when in Windows.

Comment: in Ventura 13 this is in "System Prefs" > "Keyboard Navigation" then a button for "Keyboard Shortcuts" which will open a dialog with "Mission Control" on the left and then an expandable "Mission Control" on the right with checkboxes.

Comment: @vinnyjames I spent days looking for this setting without realizing that the 'mission control' menu item was expandable!

Answer (score 10):

I updated an app called Karabiner and it turned some Mission Control shortcuts off. I like moving desktops. Here's how you turn them back on:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/W6bd9z8.png]

Comment: Is there a way to get karabiner to send "move left a space" and "move right a space" commands. I would like to continue to have control left/right to execute those commands, but I would also like to have a one handed option (eg right command comma and right command period)

Comment: @ORcoder, yes, Karabiner is quite configurable. You may need to add a rule to ~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json configuration file but it's pretty easy to do, just look at the rest of the file for examples.