# How can I make ctrl+right/left arrow jump words in Visual Studio Code

Tags: shortcut, visual-studio-code

My fingers are programmed to use ctrl+right arrow to jump a word forward, ctrl+left arrow to jump a word back, in Terminal.
[I have disabled Mission Control](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18043/how-can-i-make-ctrlright-left-arrow-stop-changing-desktops-in-lion).

I can not figure out how to get this functionality in Visual Studio Code's Integrated Terminal (in macOS obviously). vscode/Code Version 1.27.1.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Option+Left/Right is the default way to jump a word backward/forward on macOS. I know it's not what you asked for, but maybe it would be helpful for others like me.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up finding the solution via Microsoft vscode github issues:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/64972

Add these keybindings in *~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json*

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+left",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "\u001bb" },
    "when":"terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+right",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "\u001bf" },
    "when":"terminalFocus"
}
```

Tested in GNU bash version 4.4.23, (installed via homebrew `brew install bash`)

Answer (score 1):

A totally primitive solution would be to reassign the key's function.

Change the Control to Option as shown.

[image]

But that would require you to change it back for other uses.